# Activity memory management

Tags: android, android-activity

> I have basically a theoretical problem. Suppose I have two activities A and B. I am calling Activity B by A using Intent but not finishing A so basically it will go onPause(). After some task I finished Activity B so now Activity A will come in front. My question is that what happen after finish() method , cause I was told by someone that after finish() method Activity B will be in stack but not accessible. I am confuse that if it happens then is it not a waste of memory? Or if I am incorrect , please guide me in a proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I 100% understand your question. But let's try...

You start ActivityA so the activity stack in your task looks like this:

```
ActivityA (shown to user)
```

Now ActivityA starts ActivityB but does not finish itself. ActivityA is paused and ActivityB is shown to the user. Your activity stack looks like this:

```
ActivityB (shown to user)
ActivityA (paused)
```

Now the user does some stuff in ActivityB and then ActivityB calls `finish()` on itself. ActivityA is now shown to the user. Your activity stack looks like this:

```
ActivityA (shown to user)
```

At this point, ActivityB is finished and can be removed from the system. Android calls `onDestroy()` on ActivityB and the garbage collector will eventually remove it from the heap. There is no "waste of memory" here.

If I misinterpreted your question, please make a comment and I'll fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833854/fragment-and-parent-activity-life-cycle-together this is my one more silly question. Hope you can help.