# Fragment and parent activity life cycle together

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I was following these four topics [Creating a Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating), [Handling the Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) , [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) and [Pausing and Resuming an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html). So I am in a little doubt about this.
My question is

1. If A `Activity` call B `Activity` through `Intent` but A does not call `finish()` method then A will be in `Pause` state if B is `Transparent` or `SemiTransparent` and in `Stop` state if B is `Opaque`. Am I right?
2. If A `Activity` contains `Fragment` F then if A will go to `Pause` state then F will go to `Pause` state and if A will be in `Stop` state then F will be in `Stop` state too. Am I right?
3. If A calls B `Activity`  and B is `Transparent` then A will be in `Pause` state and F will too. If B call `finish()` then A will come to `Resume` state but what  will happen to F? will it come to resume from pause? If it is then how and what steps because I have not seen any direct link in `Fragment` life cycle which indicates `onPause()` to `onResume()` directly as Activity can do.

> Hope I am able to ask what I want. Sorry for my bad Englsh.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't be sure that only onPause will be called on A if B is SemiTransparent or partially visible as I understand it:

   > Paused
   >
   > Another activity is in the foreground and has focus, but this
   >   one is still visible. That is, another activity is visible on top of
   >   this one and that activity is partially transparent or doesn't cover
   >   the entire screen. A paused activity is completely alive (the Activity
   >   object is retained in memory, it maintains all state and member
   >   information, and remains attached to the window manager), but can be
   >   killed by the system in extremely low memory situations.
2. Yes, you are right:

   > The lifecycle of the activity in which the fragment lives directly
   >   affects the lifecycle of the fragment, such that each lifecycle
   >   callback for the activity results in a similar callback for each
   >   fragment. For example, when the activity receives onPause(), each
   >   fragment in the activity receives onPause().

   However, the opposite is not true, meaning that if a fragment receives onStop, that does not guarantee that the Activity's onStop will be called.
3. I am not quite sure what you mean by your last sentence or how you have tested this. According to the Fragment documentation:

   > public void onResume ()
   >
   > Called when the fragment is visible to the user
   >   and actively running. This is generally tied to Activity.onResume of
   >   the containing Activity's lifecycle

   It says generally because it depends on how the fragment is handled by the activity.

Comment: Actually I was asking in last statement that we know that when an Activity goes from onPause to onResume , it goes directly or onStop to on Resume it goes to onStop ->onRestart -> onStart->onResume. But what abt the containing fragment inside activity? you can see in fragment life cycle onPause-> onStop ->onDestroyView ->onCreateView ->onActivityCreated -> onStart ->onResume. WILL IT FOLLOW THIS? IF DON'T THEN WHY IS THIS LIFE CYCLE?

Answer (score 0):

1. If A Activity call B Activity through Intent but A does not call finish() method then A will be in Pause state if B is Transparent or SemiTransparent and in Stop state if B is Opaque. Am I right?

   **Yes true**
2. If A Activity contains Fragment F then if A will go to Pause state then F will go to Pause state and if A will be in Stop state then F will be in Stop state too. Am I right?

   **Yes correct**
3. If A calls B Activity and B is Transparent then A will be in Pause state and F will too. If B call finish() then A will come to Resume state but what will happen to F? will it come to resume from pause? If it is then how and what steps because I have not seen any direct link in Fragment life cycle which indicates onPause() to onResume() directly as Activity can do.

**What you understood is correct, even in this scenario also fragment will be moved from onPause to onResume state just like an activity.
But unfortunately there is not much documentation about this in developer android.
This might be because they wanted to avoid complicated diagrams which can create more confusion.**

Comment: Not an answer, I only find repeating the questions.